# WebAPI get access token without username and password

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Im trying to sign in a user in web api without using their Username/Password combination. I have access to the User object for the user but need to "log them in" and return the access token to the client application for subsequent requests.

I've tried variations on the following but with no luck, the `UserManager` object is disposed as soon as I call `GenerateUserIdentityAsync` the first time which causes it to fail for the `cookiesIdentity` and its warning me that my cast `OAuthGrantResourceOwnerContextCredentials` is a "Suspicious type conversion or check" but the code never reaches that line anyway; this is what Ive tried, which was taken and modified from the `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` method of my `ApplicationOAuthProvider` class. Incidentally my Token end point works perfectly with the usual `username`, `password` and `grant_type` request.

```
var user = // Super secret way of getting the user....;
Authentication.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
// UserManager is not null at this point
var oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager,
                OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
// UserManager is null at this point and so throws exception
var cookiesIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager,
                CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

var properties = ApplicationOAuthProvider.CreateProperties(user.UserName);
var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);


((OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext)HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Request.Context)
            .Validated(ticket);
        HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(cookiesIdentity);
```

In essence all I want to do is return an access token for a user for which I do not have the username and password but a "secret" that I want to use instead of username password. Is there a way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK so after much digging I found [this article](http://bitoftech.net/2014/08/11/asp-net-web-api-2-external-logins-social-logins-facebook-google-angularjs-app/) that helped me put together this code which works like a charm:

```
var user = // Super secret method of getting the user
var tokenExpiration = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName));
identity.AddClaim(new Claim("role", "user"));
var props = new AuthenticationProperties()
{
    IssuedUtc = DateTime.UtcNow,
    ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.Add(tokenExpiration),
};
var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, props);
var accessToken = Startup.OAuthOptions.AccessTokenFormat.Protect(ticket);
JObject tokenResponse = new JObject(
    new JProperty("userName", user.UserName),
    new JProperty("access_token", accessToken),
    new JProperty("token_type", "bearer"),
    new JProperty("expires_in", tokenExpiration.TotalSeconds.ToString()),
    new JProperty(".issued",
        ticket.Properties.IssuedUtc.GetValueOrDefault().DateTime.ToUniversalTime()),
    new JProperty(".expires",
        ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc.GetValueOrDefault().DateTime.ToUniversalTime()));
return tokenResponse;
```

Comment: Can you explain me what i need to put in AddClaim please? I don't understand it.

Comment: Thanks. You save my time.